# Logisim shows output as X, even though the gate is connected

Tags: logic-gates, logisim

Below is a basic NOT circuit using a NAND gate.

[image]

Not sure why output is X, when I change *Output properties* to *three state no*, I can't modify circuit.

Sometimes, these issues go away when I restart Logisim.

some more weird issues...

My ALU output shows `E`

[image]

I tracked that down to below highlighted Mux gate

[image]

When I drill down to that gate it shows `x` on output
[image]

When I tried to modify that, it gives this popup

[image]

when I click ok and try to change input, `x` in output will be gone.

All my subcircuits are fine individually, when combining them to make ALU, these kind of weird issues popup, when drilling down, we will see results like above.

Faced same issue with adder, but restarting Logisim fixed the issue.

Any ideas or pointers ...?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that simulation is enabled (in the Simulation menu). If simulation is disabled, the states of signals in your circuit will not be updated.

Comment: Actually, the simulation is enabled and even when trying to change input to 1/0 doesnt change output

Comment: when i closed this and reopened and it works.Getting strange errors like this

Comment: Weird! That's the only way I was able to reproduce the result shown in your screenshot -- if simulation is enabled, a floating (blue) input to an AND gate would normally result in an undefined (red) output, not another floating output.

Comment: Added some more data to question.Thanks for your time on this